# Tizen 6.5 WebRTC issue with video sending from a TV

Tags: tizen

I want to send through an video feed through WebRTC, this feed is renderd on a canvas, it seems that the Tizen TV can't send through video in this way, can anyone help me with this?
Interesting note: The rendering itself seems good, because I can rerender it in a  element using the stream from the canvas.

It should work on a Tizen TV, Tizen 6.5

Direct capture the stream from the canvas with the captureStream()
Indirect capture stream from the video element

Comment: Would you add some code snippet for more detailed information?

Comment: webrtc.js: https://pastebin.com/6G4vRpqM 

index.html: https://pastebin.com/ESdWSUAe Tizen config.xml: https://pastebin.com/H8vq9cf8 This is what is deployed on the TV. I used this repository as a start: github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example I modified the signaller to use HTTP instead of HTTPS and using a Caddy proxy on top of the signaller. The other side of the WebRTC uses almost the same code.